# Xamarin Android FindViewById<ListView> returns null

Tags: c#, android

I am trying to pull REST data from an api deserialise it and place it in a list. I have tried like so

```
private void ParseAndDisplay(JsonValue json)
        {
            ListView lstData = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstData);
            List<Team> list_teams = new List<Team>();
            RootObject objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json.ToString());
            foreach (var obj in objs.teams)
            {
                var id = obj._links.self.href;
                var indexOfLastBackSlash = id.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
                id = id.Substring(indexOfLastBackSlash);

                Team team = new Team();
                team.name = obj.name;
                //team.id = id;
                list_teams.Add(team);
                //var list = list_teams.ToArray();
                var slist = new List<string>();
                foreach (Team t in list_teams) { string s = t.name;
                    slist.Add(s);
                }
                var data = new string[slist.Count()];
                data = slist.ToArray();

                lstData.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,Resource.Xml.listViewTemplate, data);
            }
```

However lstData comes up as null when I try to assign it to the ArrayAdapter and an unhandled exception error occurs. I am trying to run it to my phone.

Comment: Is `ParseAndDisplay()` method called before `SetContentView()` method? Can you make sure you are passing the correct layout id in `SetContentView()`

Comment: It is called after setContentView() and definitely set to the correct layout

Comment: Is `ParseAndDisplay()` invoked on the main thread?

Comment: Yes in the OnCreate